# On click open a specific table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one div that contains 3 tables with id table1, table2 and table3 and initially tables are hidden.
There is another div which contains 3 li elements with the same id as a table. On the first li click i want to toggle the first table and table2 and table 3 will be hidden.
same as for table2 and table3. The html code is like

```
    <div class="container" >
     <table id="table1">
      <tr>A</tr>
     </table>
     <table id="table2">
      <tr>B</tr>
     </table>
     <table id="table3">
      <tr>C</tr>
     </table>
     </div>
```

Html code of another div is

```
    <div class="container2">
     <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

The first li has the same value as it is in table1. same for table2 and table3.  I am using this j query code to get the result but i am not getting the correct result. I don't want to use class or id for li. I want to execute this on the base of value because li and table have the same value.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".container2 li").click(function() {
      
     $(".container").find("#" + this.id).toggle(); 
      });
     });
```

Comment: ID's in HTML are meant to only be used once. Having multiple elements with the same ID will cause problems, like the one you are having now.

Comment: Is your html actually broken like that? Or is that a typo? (Missing ending double quotes)

Comment: @LUL won't that `li` will  contain  `a` tag?

Answer (score 3):

Try this way because id should be unique.

```
<div class="container2>
 <ul>
  <li openid="table1">A</li>
  <li openid="table2">B</li>
  <li openid="table3">C</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".container2 li").click(function() {
      var ids = $(this).attr('openid');
      $("#"+ids).toggle(); 
   });
});
```

Remember id should be unique.

In your code for two elements ids are same which is not valid. You need to define any extra attribute like `openid` or anything else in your code. and then you can get the id of that table which you want to open.

Comment: This would be better if you gave an explaination of what the jQuery code is actually doing.

Comment: @wahwahwah I have added the explanation. Hope can be useful to other also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
<div class="container" >
     <table id="table1_1">
      <tr>A</tr>
     </table>
     <table id="table2_1>
      <tr>B</tr>
     </table>
     <table id="table3_1>
      <tr>C</tr>
     </table>
     </div>
```

and use like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".container2 li").click(function() {

       $(".container").find("#" + this.id+"_1").toggle(); 
      });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate `id` suggestions are great, but that isn't actually causing any problems here and won't fix anything.

The problem is broken html markup. You just need a `td` in your `tr`

```
<table id="table1_1">
  <tr><td>A</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: actually the situation is like first li value and first table id are same. same for 2nd and 3rd li. Now what will be the solution.

Comment: @LUL check my answer where you can find the solution.

Comment: @Lul - please update your post with this new condition, don't just leave it in the comments of someone's answer

Comment: @LUL I don't understand you, and apparently you don't understand me either. This answer is the solution. There's plenty other answers though, goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

> i dont want to use class or id for li. I want to execute this on the
>   base of value because li and table has the same value.

Try utilizing `:contains()`

```js
$("table").hide(0);

$(".container2 li").on("click", function(e) {
  $("table td:contains("+ $(this).text() +")")
  .parents("table").toggle().siblings().hide(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="container">
  <table id="table1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table id="table2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table id="table3">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: initially all the table should be hide. i want one time only one table. plz update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

*[Based on comments posted in  @Stephen Bugs Kamenar's answer..]*

Given that each `<li>` has the same text / html as the `id` of the table you would like to show/hide, you can access it on the click event, and use it as a selector for the corresponding table element like so:

```
$(".container2 li").click(function () {
    var tarTable = $("#" + $(this).html());
});
```

By adding an additional class to each table element (or just using 'table' if there aren't any other's to worry about) you can ensure that only the table corresponding to the li that's been clicked is visible by using the `.not()` selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container2 li").click(function() {
    // get the target table:
    var tarTable = $("#" + $(this).html());

    // toggle:
    tarTable.toggle();

    // get all the tables with the 'table' class, except for our tarTable
    // hide them
    $('.table').not(tarTable).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#table1,
#table2,
#table3 {
  display: none;
}
td {
  border: solid 2px pink;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
  <ul>
    <li>table1</li>
    <li>table2</li>
    <li>table3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <table id="table1" class="table">
    <!-- ADDED CLASS -->
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="table2" class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="table3" class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**[Notes on the original post]**

- Be sure to use the correct html markup for the table element. All `<tr>` (table row) elements need at least one `<td>` element (table cell/data.)
- Element `id`s should only occur *once* per page - if possible (eg, if you are creating your own markup this should never need to happen)
- Make sure you are correctly closing quotes - this can also cause problems

A really good resource for testing javascript / jquery and html is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). It has "tidy up" and "jshint" features that quickly make code more readible and check for syntax errors.